# OnCollisionEnter2D(...) not called

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, detection

I want to make a Pong game with Unity, but I can't detect collisions between a ball and a boxCollider. They both have a RigidBody2D component.

This is the method :

```
void OncollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collisionInfo) 
{
    Debug.Log("Collision");
    /*if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Player") 
    {
        Debug.Log("CA MARCHE !");
    }*/
}
```

Is Kinematic and IsTrigger are unchecked for each.

Answer (score 5):

OncollisionEnter2D should be OnCollisionEnter2D I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Add colliders to both of them and use OnTriggerEnter() function instead of OnCollisionEnter().
Unity script reference: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a BoxCollider2D rather than BoxCollider. It's under Component -> Pyhsics 2D.